# Component's children should not be mutated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

имеется связка react-redux. часть хранилища redux получается через ajax и выглядит так:

```
counts: {
        warning: 0,
        new: 0,
        in_hands: 0,
        completed: 0,
        rejected: 0
    }
```

изменение этих значений ведут за собой рендер компонента:
render() {

```
        var counts = [
            {
                id: 'warning',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.warning),
                name: 'Внимение'
            },
            {
                id: 'new',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.new),
                name: 'Новые'
            },
            {
                id: 'in_hands',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.in_hands),
                name: 'В работе'
            },
            {
                id: 'completed',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.completed),
                name: 'Выполн.'
            },
            {
                id: 'rejected',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.rejected),
                name: 'Отменен.'
            }
        ];

    content = (<div className="inside-loader"/>);

    return(
        <div>
        <Tabs key="tabs_order-list" id="order-list" items={counts} defaultTab="warning" changeList={this.changeList} content={content}/></div>
    )
}
```

внутри Tabs происходит нечто такое:

```
render() {
        let self = this;
        let items = this.props.items.map(function (item, index) {
            return <div key={self.props.id+'_'+index} onClick={self.changeTab.bind(null, item.id)} className={'bar-tabs__tab ' + (self.state.openedTabId == item.id ? 'active' : '')}>
                <b>{item.count}</b>
                <span>{item.name}</span>
            </div>
        })
        return <div>
            <div className={'bar-tabs bar-tabs__' + this.props.id}>{items}</div>
            <div className={'bar-tabs-content bar-tabs-content__' + this.props.id}>
                <div className='bar-tabs-content__tab active'>{this.props.content}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

как видно, я получаю данные, форматирую их в массив и передаю в Tabs. При этом возникает вот такой warning:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почитав схожие проблемы я понял, что такая ошибка возникает, когда мы изменяем данные, но я их не изменяю

Comment: Просто погулите проблему. Есть к примеру баг за август... если в тег вставлять NaN, то всплывает такое сообщение. Просто убирайте блоки в render по очереди, чтобы выявить проблемное место. parseInt у вас вполне где-то может вернуть NaN